# is there a way to indirectly uncharge rapidly a coin cell to defeat an anti tampering mechanism?

Tags: penetration-test, tamper-resistance, tampering

An anti tampering mechanism of a device relay on detect tampering mechanism when the device is powered down using the energy provided internally by a coin cell.

Is there a way to uncharge rapidly a coin cell contained in a device without having access to the coin cell and the electronic that use it ?

I'm trying to thinking out of the box (probably in a stupid way). What about ?

- microwave effect
- high/low temperature
- increase/decrease humidity
- ?-ray from a medical equipment

Comment: A particularly powerful electromagnetic pulse may do the trick, but not because it would discharge the cell. A strong enough pulse would damage the tamper-detection circuitry, and very possibly short circuit it, depriving all the circuitry of power. Depending on how well it is designed, even putting it near a plasma globe may have this effect. Pocket calculators have a tendency to lock up in that situation, as do small handheld video game systems.

Answer (score 1):

In order to rapidly discharge a battery the energy has to go somewhere. You would have to either physically contact the coin cell and cause a drain, or somehow cause the electronics to do it for you. Whether the electronics would have the capability to cause that drain is another question. Most devices are designed to conserve the power of their backup batteries so my guess would be a no.

Comment: What about increasing temperature/humidity of the room or something like that ?

Comment: Temperature extremes may have an effect of some kind, but would be marginal.

Comment: what about microwave ? humidity ? magnetic ray from a medical equipment ?

Comment: No, no, and no.

Comment: I can't believe it's not crackable :D

Comment: A strong x-ray pulse can "freeze" some CMOS memory, but the amount required is far beyond what medical equipment is designed to output.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the general case.

You could somehow drill in to the device and disconnect the battery, but if doing so triggers the anti-tampering technology, then you have to think of a different way in.

There is no environmental factor which will discharge a battery without a load in any reasonable amount of time. Given a few years, perhaps. But a few hours? Nope.

Answer (score 1):

Extreme cold will not discharge the battery, but may drop its voltage enough to make the electronics inoperant.

With lithium batteries, cold enough is really really cold, so maybe you'll have to use dry ice (take safety precautions). This is well known so some anti tampering mechanics actually test for temperature and trigger some last ditch safety measure if something suspicious happens.

Comment: Indeed digging more in I've found that the anti-tampering mechanism for this device monitors the temperature.